# Using a Multidimensional Associative Array to create a Windows Directory Structure

Tags: php, arrays, loops, directory, mkdir

I have a multidimensional associative array that represents a directory structure. The structure info is pulled from a database with `parent_id`s to dictate the hierarchy.

I've successfully gotten the rows from the db and sorted into an array similar to this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [fold_id] => 1
            [fold_name] => Preliminary
            [seq] => 1
            [parent_id] => 0
            [generation] => 1
            [ext_name] => 1 Preliminary
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [fold_id] => 9
                            [fold_name] => Programming
                            [seq] => 3
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [generation] => 2
                            [ext_name] => 1.3 Programming
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [10] => Array
                                        (
                                            [fold_id] => 10
                                            [fold_name] => Feasibility Study
                                            [seq] => 
                                            [parent_id] => 9
                                            [generation] => 3
                                            [ext_name] => Feasibility Study
                                        )

                                    [11] => Array
                                        (
                                            [fold_id] => 11
                                            [fold_name] => Field Investigation
                                            [seq] => 
                                            [parent_id] => 9
                                            [generation] => 3
                                            [ext_name] => Field Investigation
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )           
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fold_id] => 2
            [fold_name] => Construction Documents
            [seq] => 2
            [parent_id] => 0
            [generation] => 1
            [ext_name] => 2 Construction Documents
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [fold_id] => 12
                            [fold_name] => Code
                            [seq] => 1
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [generation] => 2
                            [ext_name] => 2.1 Code
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [fold_id] => 13
                            [fold_name] => Drawing
                            [seq] => 2
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [generation] => 2
                            [ext_name] => 2.2 Drawing
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [17] => Array
                                        (
                                            [fold_id] => 17
                                            [fold_name] => Families
                                            [seq] => 
                                            [parent_id] => 13
                                            [generation] => 3
                                            [ext_name] => Families
                                        )
                                )
                            
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [fold_id] => 14
                            [fold_name] => Specs
                            [seq] => 3
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [generation] => 2
                            [ext_name] => 2.3 Specs
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [19] => Array
                                        (
                                            [fold_id] => 19
                                            [fold_name] => Cut Sheets
                                            [seq] => 
                                            [parent_id] => 14
                                            [generation] => 3
                                            [ext_name] => Cut Sheets
                                        )

                                    [20] => Array
                                        (
                                            [fold_id] => 20
                                            [fold_name] => Front-End Documents
                                            [seq] => 
                                            [parent_id] => 14
                                            [generation] => 3
                                            [ext_name] => Front-End Documents
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )      
        )
)
```

The `ext_name` key in each child array is the actual folder name. What I need to do is take this array and create an actual directory structure from it using `mkdir()`.

I have done so by hard-coding a foreach loop for each nested generation, but I'd like to somehow do it in a way that allows the structure to change without my code having to be updated, to accommodate more generations, for example.

Any of you php gurus out there have a more elegant solution?

Thanks!!!
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with. Seems to work! I'm open to improvements!!!

```
function make_paths(&$tree, $parentPath = '') {
    $pathed = array();

    foreach ($tree AS &$branch) {

        if ( strlen($parentPath) ) {
            $path = $parentPath.'/'.$branch['ext_name'];
        } else {
            $path = $branch['ext_name'];
        }

        if ( array_key_exists('children', $branch) ) {
            $children = make_paths( $branch['children'], $path );
            $pathed[] = $path;
            $pathed[] = $children;
        } else {
            $pathed[] = $path;
        }

        unset($branch);
    }
    return $pathed;
}
```

Then I just used `array_walk_recursive()` to grab the paths and make the folders.

Comment: You could write a second implementation that uses a stack and not recursion. Not that recursion would be wrong, just to do it both ways. And you could peek into RecursiveIteratorIterator and the RecursiveArrayIterator. - https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php